# How to color selectInput placeholder prompt in Shiny?

Tags: css, r, shiny

I wanted to make blue colored "Choose" prompt in `SelectInput` box (Segment mIgration) so that it looks similar to other input boxes but failed.
[image]

Here is the piece of code I used in UI section:

```
  column(width=2,
       selectInput(inputId = "SEG_MIG",
                   label = "Segment Migration",
                   choices =c("Choose"='', "ALL",
                              unique(sort(as.character(final_data$`SEG MIG`)))),
                   multiple = TRUE
                   ))
```

Selected elements in two inputbox on the left were colored blue with this piece of code

```
  tags$style(type='text/css', ".selectize-input { font-size: 16px; line-height: 16px; color: blue;} 
                           .selectize-dropdown { background: grey; color: white; font-size: 12px; line-height: 12px; }"),
```

I am not sure what did I miss here. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want all items in blue, or only "Choose" ?

Comment: Hello Stephane, I want all of them blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the CSS to control the style of the options, the items, and the placeholder.

```
library(shiny)

css <- "
.selectize-dropdown-content .option {
  color: blue;
}
.selectize-input .item {
  color: red !important;
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: pink;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: pink;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: pink;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: pink;
}"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(css))
  ),
  column(width=2,
         selectInput(inputId = "SEG_MIG",
                     label = "Segment Migration",
                     choices = c("Choose"='', "ALL", "AAA", "BBB"),
                     multiple = TRUE
         )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Stephane Laurent