# How to customise background colors in shinydashoard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have the following webapp in R (Shiny). I'm trying to change the background color of the header, however the background color in the title corner remains as the default. Is there a way to fix this?

Also, what is the best way to go about changing the background colors of the `sidebar` and `selectizeInput` boxes to custom colors as well?

```
ibrary(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- dashboardPage(
                    dashboardHeader(title = 'Hello'),
                    dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu
                                                (menuItem(tabName = 'Panel1', text = ' Growth Heatmap'),
                                                 dateInput("Start_Date", "Start Date", min = '2000-01-01', max = Sys.Date(), value = '2020-01-01',format = "yyyy-mm-dd")
                                                )
                                     ),
                    dashboardBody(tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.skin-blue .main-header .navbar {background-color: #22313f;}'))),
                                  tabItems(tabItem(tabName = 'Panel1',
                                                   fluidRow(box(selectizeInput('select_mean', 'Select Number', choices = c(12,24,36,48,60,120)),height=80,width=4)),
                                                   fluidRow(box(width = 13, height = 655))
                                                   )
                                           )
                                  )
                    
)


server <- function(input, output) {


}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: You'll need to define the CSS style for those elements.  If you press F12 in most modern browsers or or right click and select "inspect element" you can view the underlying structure - mouse over the relevant area to find out their classes for styling.

Comment: Please check library([fresh](https://github.com/dreamRs/fresh)).

Comment: For the colors of the `selectizeInput` see <https://stackoverflow.com/a/55187295/1100107>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   .skin-blue .main-header .logo {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;
}
   .skin-blue .main-header .logo:hover {
    background-color: black;
  }
```

adding this to css file should change the header logo background color to black and text white.
Here is the link for css file see line (1-139) for blue skin-
[shinydashboard_blue_skin](https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/blob/main/inst/AdminLTE/_all-skins.css)
I think you have to play around little bit with color (search sidebar in the above css file and you will  find where to change)